# How to set a Principal within a HandshakeInterceptor

Tags: spring-websocket

I'm using a very thin implementation of Spring's WebSockets. WebSocketSession has the method getPrincipal(), but how can I set it from within a HandshakeInterceptor?

The method I would like to put the Principal in is:

```
public boolean beforeHandshake(final ServerHttpRequest request, final ServerHttpResponse response, final WebSocketHandler wsHandler,
        final Map<String, Object> attributes) throws Exception {
    Principal = getPrincipal();
    // Now where to set the principal so it is available in WebSocketSession?

}
```

Comment: See the source code of `DefaultHandshakeHandler`: how it gets deal with `RequestUpgradeStrategy`. And further any `RequestUpgradeStrategy` implementation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
registry.addEndpoint("/hello") 
.setHandshakeHandler(new DefaultHandshakeHandler() {
     @Override
     protected Principal determineUser(ServerHttpRequest request, WebSocketHandler wsHandler, Map<String, Object> attributes) {

 //Here you can set and return principal that is used by websocket session.            
}
```