# Why is SimpUserRegistry not working properly on EC2 Instance

Tags: java, amazon-ec2, websocket, spring-websocket, spring-messaging

I am using `SimpUserRegistry` to get online user-count (with `getUserCount()`). And it is working good on my local machines but not on AWS EC2 instances (tried with Amazon Linux and Ubuntu) with just elastic IP and no load balancer.

The problem on EC2 is that some users, when connected, are never added to the registry and thus I get wrong results.

I have session listeners, for `SessionConnectedEvent` and `SessionDisconnectEvent`, where I use the `SimpUserRegistry` (autowired) to get the user presence. If it matters, I am also `SimpUserRegistry` is a messaging controller.

Below is the websocket message broker config:

```
@Order(Ordered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE + 99)
@Configuration
@EnableWebSocketMessageBroker
@RequiredArgsConstructor(onConstructor = @__(@Autowired))
public class WebSocketMessageBrokerConfig extends AbstractWebSocketMessageBrokerConfigurer {

    @NonNull
    private SecurityChannelInterceptor securityChannelInterceptor;

    @Override
    public void configureMessageBroker(MessageBrokerRegistry config) {
        ThreadPoolTaskScheduler threadPoolTaskScheduler = new ThreadPoolTaskScheduler();
        threadPoolTaskScheduler.setPoolSize(1);
        threadPoolTaskScheduler.setThreadGroupName("cb-heartbeat-");
        threadPoolTaskScheduler.initialize();

        config.enableSimpleBroker("/queue/", "/topic/")
                .setTaskScheduler(threadPoolTaskScheduler)
                .setHeartbeatValue(new long[] {1000, 1000});

        config.setApplicationDestinationPrefixes("/app");
    }

    @Override
    public void registerStompEndpoints(StompEndpointRegistry registry) {
        registry.addEndpoint("/websocket")
                .setAllowedOrigins("*")
                .withSockJS();
    }

    @Override
    public void configureClientInboundChannel(ChannelRegistration registration) {
        registration.interceptors(securityChannelInterceptor);
    }
}
```

And below is the channel interceptor used in above config class:

```
@Slf4j
@Component
@RequiredArgsConstructor(onConstructor = @__(@Autowired))
public class SecurityChannelInterceptor extends ChannelInterceptorAdapter {

    @NonNull
    private SecurityService securityService;


    @Value("${app.auth.token.header}")
    private String authTokenHeader;



    @Override
    public Message<?> preSend(Message<?> message, MessageChannel channel) {
        StompHeaderAccessor accessor = MessageHeaderAccessor.getAccessor(message, StompHeaderAccessor.class);
        StompCommand command = accessor.getCommand();

        if (StompCommand.CONNECT.equals(command)) {
            List<String> authTokenList = accessor.getNativeHeader(authTokenHeader);
            if (authTokenList == null || authTokenList.isEmpty()) {
                throw new AuthenticationFailureException("STOMP " + command + " missing " + this.authTokenHeader + " header!");
            }
            String accessToken = authTokenList.get(0);
            AppAuth authentication = securityService.authenticate(accessToken);
            log.info("STOMP {} authenticated. Authentication Token = {}", command, authentication);
            accessor.setUser(authentication);
            SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(authentication);

            Principal principal = accessor.getUser();
            if (principal == null) {
                throw new RuntimeException("StompHeaderAccessor did not set the authenticated User for " + authentication);
            }
        }

        return message;
    }

}
```

I also have following scheduled task which simply prints the user names every two seconds:

```
@Component
@Slf4j
@AllArgsConstructor(onConstructor = @__(@Autowired))
public class UserRegistryLoggingTask {

    private SimpUserRegistry simpUserRegistry;

    @Scheduled(fixedRate = 2000)
    public void logUsersInUserRegistry() {
        Set<String> userNames = simpUserRegistry.getUsers().stream().map(u -> u.getName()).collect(Collectors.toSet());
        log.info("UserRegistry has {} users with IDs {}", userNames.size(), userNames);
    }
}
```

And some user names never show up even when connected.

The implementation of `SecurityService` class -

```
@Service
@AllArgsConstructor(onConstructor = @__(@Autowired))
public class SecurityService {

    private UserRepository userRepository;
    private UserCredentialsRepository userCredentialsRepository;
    private JwtHelper jwtHelper;

    public User getUser() {
        AppAuth auth = (AppAuth) SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
        User user = (User) auth.getUser();
        return user;
    }

    public AppAuth authenticate(String accessToken) {
        String username = jwtHelper.tryExtractSubject(accessToken);
        if (username == null) {
            throw new AuthenticationFailureException("Invalid access token!");
        }

        User user = userRepository.findByUsername(username);
        if (user == null) {
            throw new AuthenticationFailureException("Invalid access token!");
        }

        AppAuth authentication = new AppAuth(user);
        return authentication;
    }
}
```

**Update**

Following is an example of SockJS logs on browser -

Correct response from server with `user-name` header:

```
>>> CONNECT
AccessToken:eyJhbGciOiJIUzUxMiJ9.eyJzdWIiOiJkb2cifQ.Wf8AO77LluHEfEv61TIvugEXxOqIXKjsJBO8QMQh-rF7tzf56lBkdpOruqc7UPf_Pmj6-dnHZ5raq2MnMpeG8Q
accept-version:1.1,1.0
heart-beat:10000,10000

<<< CONNECTED
version:1.1
heart-beat:1000,1000
user-name:5a590e411b96f841cc00027f
```

Incorrect response from server with no `user-name` header:

```
>>> CONNECT
AccessToken:eyJhbGciOiJIUzUxMiJ9.eyJzdWIiOiJtb3VzZSJ9.wqX5X_CSdHD8_7PZPiSzftGCuPz1ClQU0-F9RHCqOIIkMLzI4rt31_EAaykc8VojK2KGS6DcycWfAdMr2edzYg
accept-version:1.1,1.0
heart-beat:10000,10000

<<< CONNECTED
version:1.1
heart-beat:1000,1000
```

I have also verified that the `SecurityChannelInterceptor` is authenticating all the users, even when the `user-name` is not in the `CONNECTED` response.

**Update**

I deployed the app on heroku. And the issue is happening there as well.

**Update**

When issue occurs, `user` in `SessionConnectEvent` is the one set by `SecurityChannelInterceptor` but `user` in `SessionConnectedEvent` is `null`.

**Update**

`AppAuth` class -

```
public class AppAuth implements Authentication {

    private final User user;
    private final Collection<GrantedAuthority> authorities;


    public AppAuth(User user) {
        this.user = user;
        this.authorities = Collections.singleton((GrantedAuthority) () -> "USER");
    }

    public User getUser() {
        return this.user;
    }

    @Override
    public String getName() {
        return user.getId();
    }

    @Override
    public Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> getAuthorities() {
        return authorities;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getCredentials() {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getDetails() {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getPrincipal() {
        return new Principal() {
            @Override
            public String getName() {
                return user.getId();
            }
        };
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isAuthenticated() {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void setAuthenticated(boolean isAuthenticated) throws IllegalArgumentException {

    }
}
```

Comment: Can you provide the implementation of your security service?

Comment: @vsoni I have added `SecurityService` implementation class.

Comment: Did you notice any difference in the logs of the two environments?

Comment: You are using `DefaultSimpUserRegistry` as implementation of `SimpUserRegistry`?

Comment: @dpr Yes, it is `DefaultSimpUserRegistry`.

Comment: @vsoni Updated the post with some new findings.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was able to track the issue after some debugging by adding a few logger statements in the `StompSubProtocolHandler`.
After finding the cause, conclusion was that a channel-interceptor is not a correct place to authenticate an user. At least for my use-case.

Following are some of the code snippets from  [`StompSubProtocolHandler`](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/v4.3.14.RELEASE/spring-websocket/src/main/java/org/springframework/web/socket/messaging/StompSubProtocolHandler.java) -

The `handleMessageFromClient` method adds the user to the `stompAuthentications` map and publishes a `SessionConnectEvent` event -

```
public void handleMessageFromClient(WebSocketSession session, WebSocketMessage<?> webSocketMessage, MessageChannel outputChannel) {
    //...
    SimpAttributesContextHolder.setAttributesFromMessage(message);
    boolean sent = outputChannel.send(message);

    if (sent) {
        if (isConnect) {
            Principal user = headerAccessor.getUser();
            if (user != null && user != session.getPrincipal()) {
                this.stompAuthentications.put(session.getId(), user);
            }
        }
        if (this.eventPublisher != null) {
            if (isConnect) {
                publishEvent(new SessionConnectEvent(this, message, getUser(session)));
            }
    //...
```

And the `handleMessageToClient` retrieves the user from the `stompAuthentications` map and publishes a `SessionConnectedEvent` -

```
public void handleMessageToClient(WebSocketSession session, Message<?> message) {
    //...
    SimpAttributes simpAttributes = new SimpAttributes(session.getId(), session.getAttributes());
    SimpAttributesContextHolder.setAttributes(simpAttributes);
    Principal user = getUser(session);
    publishEvent(new SessionConnectedEvent(this, (Message<byte[]>) message, user));
    //...
```

`getUser` method used by above methods -

```
private Principal getUser(WebSocketSession session) {
    Principal user = this.stompAuthentications.get(session.getId());
    return user != null ? user : session.getPrincipal();
}
```

Now, the problem occurs when the `handleMessageToClient` snippet executes before the `handleMessageFromClient` snippet. In this case, user is never added to the `DefaultSimpUserRegistry`, as it only checks the `SessionConnectedEvent`.

Below is the event listener snippet from [`DefaultSimpUserRegistry`](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/v4.3.14.RELEASE/spring-websocket/src/main/java/org/springframework/web/socket/messaging/DefaultSimpUserRegistry.java) -

```
public void onApplicationEvent(ApplicationEvent event) {
    //...
    else if (event instanceof SessionConnectedEvent) {
        Principal user = subProtocolEvent.getUser();
        if (user == null) {
            return;
        }
    //...
```

**Solution**

The solution is to extend [`DefaultHandshakeHandler`](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/v4.3.14.RELEASE/spring-websocket/src/main/java/org/springframework/web/socket/server/support/DefaultHandshakeHandler.java) and override `determineUser` method, which is based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33537534/738746). But, as I am using SockJS, this requires the client to send auth-token as a query parameter. And the reason for the query parameter requirement is discussed [here](https://github.com/sockjs/sockjs-client/issues/196).

Answer (score 1):

Just a few points that may help you in resolving the problem.

1. Clearly for some of the users the `authentication` is not being set. Did you notice any pattern, in which condition the `authentication` is not set? Going through the source code of [DefaultSimpUserRegistry](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/master/spring-websocket/src/main/java/org/springframework/web/socket/messaging/DefaultSimpUserRegistry.java) and [StompSubProtocolHandler](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/master/spring-websocket/src/main/java/org/springframework/web/socket/messaging/StompSubProtocolHandler.java) reaffirms `authentication/principle` not being set for some of the users. That is why users are missing from SimpUserRegistry.
2. Going through this - [Websocket Authentication and Authorization in Spring](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45405332/websocket-authentication-and-authorization-in-spring) . It suggests, the `authentication` perhaps not set if `GrantedAuthorities` is missing in the `authentication/principle`.
3. You can probably check the creation of your `AppAuth` object and see if the `GrantedAuthorities` is properly set for all the users.

Hope this may help someway in resolving your issue.

Comment: Authentication is very simple and only for identification. There is no concept of authorization. But I had read about the authorities and put one in there anyway. You can see it in the update on the post. So, if you look at it, it should be same for all the users.

Comment: Also, I am using same database (mongodb cloud) from my machine and cloud machines (EC2 and heroku). And I have never experienced this issue on my machine.